# Is it possible to add a new column in a stored procedure in db2?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Hi I'm a junior developer, I just want to ask Is it possible to add a new column in a stored procedure in db2? what i mean like an alter table for adding a new column but in stored procedure?

Comment: Question is, _why_ do you want to do this?  Consider that if the procedure is called from a loop, you may end up with multiple such columns, which may not be what you want.  Usually the schema of tables changes "slowly", and manually, not via stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you have to use dynamic sql.

```
--# SET TERMINATOR @
create table test_add_col(a int) in userspace1@

begin
  execute immediate 'alter table test_add_col add b int';
end@

select colname 
from syscat.columns 
where tabschema=user and tabname='TEST_ADD_COL'@
```

The result is:

> COLNAME
>    --
>   A
>   B